# Trying to create a dynamic search/filter table for 25 thousand rows of NBA data using Django, Postgresql, and Jquery

Tags: python, html, jquery, django, postgresql

But I have no idea what I'm doing.

Now this is how far I've gotten:

views.py:

```
    statsReg = list(seasonstats.objects.filter(pts__gt=2000).order_by('pts')[0:5].values())
    stats = simplejson.dumps(statsReg)
    return render(request, 'djangotest.html', {'stats': stats})
```

html:

```
    <table border="1", id="players", class="text-center">
        <tr>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Player</th>
            <th>Pos</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Tm</th>
            <th>G</th>
            <th>GS</th>
            <th>MP</th>
            <th>PER</th>
            <th>TS%</th>
            <th>Points</th>

        </tr>
        <tbody id="myTable"></tbody>
    </table>

    <script>
        var myArray = {{ stats|safe }};

        buildTable(myArray)

        function buildTable(data){
            var table = document.getElementById('myTable')
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                var row = `<tr>
                                <td>${data[i].year}</td>
                                <td>${data[i].player}</td>
                                <td>${data[i].pos}</td>
                                <td>${data[i].age}</td>
                                <td>${data[i].tm}</td>
                                <td>${data[i].g}</td>
                                <td>${data[i].gs}</td>
                                <td>${data[i].mp}</td>
                                <td>${data[i].per}</td>
                                <td>${data[i].tspercent}</td>
                                <td>${data[i].pts}</td>
                           </tr>`
                table.innerHTML += row

            }
        }
    </script>
```

So this code displays five rows of statistics correctly in a table on my page, but I have a few questions on where to go from here.

My first question is if i'm even accessing postgres with this mode.objects call, I've migrated the model to my database and can browse it in psql, but I just don't get how this works.

My second question is how I would alter the query by use of a button to for instance, increase the value in the [0:5] part of the query, or change the filter or order.

Any comments would be greatly appreciated!